# argument of type 'builtin_function_or_method' is not iterable while using openpyxl to add-chart

Tags: openpyxl

I am trying to add a chart on multiple sheets in a XLSX file:

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.chart import BarChart, Series, Reference
import glob
import os

def chartgen(filename):

    wbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename)
    sheets= wbook.sheetnames
    for i in sheets:
        chart1 = BarChart()
        chart1.type = "col"
        chart1.grouping = "stacked"
        chart1.overlap = 100
        chart1.style = 10
        chart1.title = 'Chart'
        chart1.y_axis.title = 'Y_Axis'
        #chart1.x_axis.title = 'X_Axis'
        data = Reference(datasheet, min_col=2, min_row=2, max_row=6, max_col=7) #--y_axis
        cats = Reference(datasheet, min_col=1, min_row=2, max_row=6) #--x_axis
        chart1.add_data(data, titles_from_data=True)
        chart1.set_categories(cats)
        chart1.legend = None

        i.add_chart(chart1, "B3")
        wbook.save(filename)


filenames = glob.glob('test/test.xlsx')
for filename in filenames:
    chartgen(filename)
```

But I always got

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "chart.py", line 36, in
>
> chartgen(filename)   File "chart.py", line 26, in chartgen
> chart1.add_data(data, titles_from_data=True)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/openpyxl/chart/_chart.py",
> line 168, in add_data
> range_string = u"{0}!{1}:{2}".format(data.sheetname, v[0], v[-1])   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/openpyxl/chart/reference.py",
> line 132, in sheetname
> return quote_sheetname(self.worksheet.title)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/openpyxl/utils/cell.py", line
> 221, in quote_sheetname
> if "'" in sheetname:

I also tried to create a new tab named chart after each data tab:

```
wbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename)
sheets= wbook.sheetnames
for i in sheets:
    try:
       reportsheet=wbook['chart']
    except KeyError:
        print(str('Creating chart from data, sheet name: ' + i + '_chart'))
        wbook.create_sheet('chart')
        reportsheet=wbook['chart']
```

This failed too. Due to duplicate chart tab name as `chart?`

Thanks!

Comment: Please include the full traceback.

Comment: I changed the for i loop to:

for i in range(0, len(datasheets), 1):

Comment: I changed the for i loop to:

for i in range(0, len(datasheets), 1):

And:

        data = Reference(wbook[datasheets[i]], min_col=2, min_row=2, max_row=6, max_col=7) #--y_axis
        cats = Reference(wbook[datasheets[i]], min_col=1, min_row=2, max_row=6) #--x_axis

This seems be okay, but I cannot give the new tab name as datasheetname+'chart'